# Volley use in android program

Tags: android, performance

I don't have any idea About Volley.
Please explain what is Volley in android  and how we can use this in our program.

I am really sorry for my bad english.

Comment: http://www.michenux.net/android-volley-and-gson-tutorial-797.html, http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/, http://www.technotalkative.com/android-volley-library-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volley is new framework has supported by Google Developers, with **main purpose for easily and improve to access network.**

You can find out anything related to Volley by accessing [**Google I/O 2013 - Volley: Easy, Fast Networking for Android**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo&feature=c4-overview-vl&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJOOTFfYzhR2d-rcSbBbEE_)

You should follow this,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**Volley is a library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster.**

It manages the processing and caching of network requests and it saves developers valuable time from writing the same network call/cache code again and again. And one more benefit of having less code is less number of bugs.

**Advantages of using Volley:**

- Volley automatically schedule all network requests. It means that
- Volley will be taking care of all the network requests your app
  executes for fetching response or image from web.
- Volley provides transparent disk and memory caching.
- Volley provides powerful cancellation request API. It means that you
  can cancel a single request or you can set blocks or scopes of
  requests to cancel.
- Volley provides powerful customization abilities.   Volley provides
  Debugging and tracing tools.

Check out more [How to get started Volley?](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library)